# Git apply some changes from master/branch from master to old release

Tags: git

i branches like that:

```
Master -> A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> K (merge) -> M -> N
Release    \-> G -> H     \          /
DEV                        \-> I -> J
```

I want to merge I and J commits from DEV into Release branch.
(It may be more commits, but to simplify i want only this two).

How can I do this ?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `checkout Release` and `merge DEV`?

Comment: If there are other commits on `DEV`, cherry-pick `I` and `J` on `Releases`.

Comment: Merge dev will add B and C to release. I don't want them

Answer (score 1):

One way: Check out release; then cherry pick I, then cherry pick J.

This will "apply the changes" by copying the commits and replaying their effects as new commits. But it will not form a topological merge commit.